# '&:' usage with 'is_a(Integer)'

Tags: ruby

I would like this code:

```
[1,2,3].all? {|x| x.is_a?(Integer)}
```

to work using the `&:` method like:

```
[1,2,3].all?(&:is_a?(Integer))
```

but I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

I guess it's because I am calling `is_a?(Integer)` as a symbol.

How can I pass Integer to `:is_a?`?

Comment: btw, you can use `[1,2,3].all?(Integer)` since 2.5.0

Comment: @Ilya: hah, this was the first thing I tried, and was surprised to find it not working. Turns out, I tried it in irb 2.4.3. At least they fixed it later.

Comment: @Ilya Well, for some reason it gave me an error, I saw it was a proper way to do it in the ruby doc, maybe I've made an error, I'll recheck tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible. You cannot pass `Integer` (or anything else) to a symbol `:is_a?`. A symbol does not take an argument. No object in Ruby takes an argument (without a method call).

By the way, there is no such thing as `&:`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess I'll have to use the normal method then

Comment: "there is no such thing as `&:`" - you're right, of course, but I want to point out that this initial impression of magical incantation is _really_ hard to shake off. Even though I _know_ how it works (for several years), I _still_ think of `&:to_i` as one indivisible syntactical element. :) Ruby has so much magic that it sometimes hurts the learners.

Comment: just to reiterate the "magic" @SergioTulentsev mentioned, while you cannot call `[1,2,3].all?(&:is_a?(Integer))` you could get the same result from `[1,2,3].all?(&Integer.method(:===)) #=> true`. This expands into `[1,2,3].all? { |x| Integer.===(x) }` using case equality to check if `x` is an instance of `Integer` or one of its descendants. This is how 2.5.0 implemented `all?(Integer`)

Answer (score 2):

You can get close to the notation you want with a lambda:

```
is_an_int = ->(o) { o.is_a?(Integer) }
[1,2,3].all?(&is_an_int)
```

or even closer, a lambda which returns a lambda:

```
is_a = ->(c) { ->(o) { o.is_a?(c) } }
[1,2,3].all?(&is_a[Integer])
```

Possibly more trouble than it is worth in this case but useful techniques none the less.

Comment: `is_a = ->(a,b) { b.is_a?(a)}.curry(2)` then call as `[1,2,3].all?(&is_a.(Integer))` comes pretty close too excepting the need to define the Proc first

Comment: @engineersmnky Nice one. But I have to admit that the `.(...)` syntax makes my eyes bug out so I always use `[]` to call my lambdas and pretend that I'm still a mathematician so arrays and hashes are just special types of functions anyway.

Comment: I agree although I dislike both forms, `.(...)` due to attention requirement and `[...]` due to ambiguity. I generally prefer an explicit `.call(...)` for clarity's sake